# Python, pydub splitting an audio file

Tags: python, pydub

Hi I am using pydub to split an audio file, giving the ranges to take segments from the original.

What I have is:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound_file = AudioSegment.from_mp3("C:\\audio file.mp3")

# milliseconds in the sound track
ranges = [(30000,40000),(50000,60000),(80000,90000),(100000,110000),(150000,180000)] 

for x, y in ranges:
    new_file = sound_file[x : y]
    new_file.export("C:\\" + str(x) + "-" + str(y) +".mp3", format="mp3")
```

It works well for the first 3 new files. However not the rest - it doesn’t split accordingly.

Does the problem lie in the way I give the range?

Thank you.

**Add-on:**

When it's made simple - for example

```
sound_file[150000:180000]
```

and export it to a mp3 file. it works but only cuts 50000:80000 part. it seems not reading a correct range.

Comment: are you sure your audio file is at least 180 seconds long?

Comment: @Jiaaro, thank you for the comment. yes, the audio file is very long to have all the ranges covered.

Comment: are you able to reproduce it with a simpler example? like `len(sound_file[150000:180000])` ?

Comment: @Jiaaro, thank you. when it's made simple (a segment instead of several segments). like sound_file[150000:180000] then export it to a mp3 file. it works but only cuts 50000:80000 part. it seems not reading a correct range.

Comment: are you able to share the audio file in question? it seems like there must be more to this

Comment: @Jiaaro, thank you for the continuous attention. the file is here https://www.masstamilan.com/dl/onlyurl/6968. for example I use the ranges = [(50000,80000),(150000,180000),]. the 1st segment cuts ok but the 2nd doesn't produce a right range.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might work

```
import pydub
import numpy as np
sound_file = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3("a.mp3")
sound_file_Value = np.array(sound_file.get_array_of_samples())
# milliseconds in the sound track
ranges = [(30000,40000),(50000,60000),(80000,90000),(100000,110000),(150000,180000)] 

for x, y in ranges:
    new_file=sound_file_Value[x : y]
    song = pydub.AudioSegment(new_file.tobytes(), frame_rate=sound_file.frame_rate,sample_width=sound_file.sample_width,channels=1)
    song.export(str(x) + "-" + str(y) +".mp3", format="mp3")
```